# Using op amp to turn AC 55 kHz from 5 Vpp to 30 Vpp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, ac, signal

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyTM87.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to augment a 55 kHz 5 Vpp sine wave using an LM324N op amp.
The potentiometer is so I can easily slide the signal to the desired amplitude.

The circuit works for signals up to 10 kHz, having an output of 30 Vpp, but frequencies higher than that won't be amplified.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: At least the lm324n of Texas Instruments does no more than +-16V supply, so that 30 Vpp is uncomfortably close to the maximum possible supply. What is the supply voltage you're using? How much current can your source supply, and how much current so you need at the output of your circuit?

Comment: (by the way, it's very rare to see a circuit being developed with the LM324**N**, as it's kind of forty years superseded by the LM324**B**. I would actually be surprised if the LM324N was still being produced, as it makes no commercial sense to keep both masks around, and the older process running)

Comment: Suggest you remove the ground from the 'top' connection of R2 (leave it open). It does nothing good for you.

Comment: I don't think LM324N is suitable for high frequency or high voltage applicaion. Its main advantage is low power, close-to-ground operation. Its nonsymmetric output stage makes it performs worse than normal general purpose opamp. If you need cheap opamp, try JRC4558D.

Comment: How about just a transformer?

Comment: I agree that the LM324 quad and LM358 dual are lousy old opamps. The newer B versions have the same slew rate problem above 2kHz. Most newer opamps have no problem producing high levels to 100kHz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the GBW product is given as 1 MHz which theoretically means the gain can be as high as 18 V/V for 55 kHz regardless of the amplitude, practically the voltage swing is still frequency-limited because of the relatively lower [slew rate](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Slew_rate) – Datasheet doesn't mention a number but expect around **0.5 V/μs**, so for a 55-kHz signal if we assume the voltage reaches its peak from zero in 4.5 μs *(like a triangular wave with T<sub>P</sub> = 18 μs)* then the max non-distorted swing will be less than 2.5 V.

As can be seen from the frequency response plot shown on p.9 of [LM324N](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2902-n.pdf) datasheet, the voltage swing can't reach the supply rails above 10 kHz:

[image]

<sup>**NOTE-1:** No capacitance value is given for the coupling cap in the test circuit above. So I assume it's high enough not to affect the frequency response.</sup>

<sup>**NOTE-2:** Even the simulation using the TI LMX24 model verifies this i.e. the crossover distortion becomes apparent from 5 kHz.</sup>

This means that if your input signal was, say, 50 mVpp instead of 5 Vpp then you would have got a non-distorted, clean, amplified signal.

So maybe you should try an op amp with higher bandwidth as well as a higher slew rate (at least 10 V/μs) such as [TL08X](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl082-n.pdf) which used to be (maybe still is) quite popular amongst audio-frequency applications:

[image]

**FINAL NOTE:** If your application circuit is exactly as shown in your schematic, please note that you'll be loading/pushing the op-amp more as you try to increase the gain. Avoid doing that. Select relatively higher resistors but take the input bias into account.

Comment: I used the TL084 as per your advice and got the result I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @HTZ If my answer is satisfactory enough (apparently it is as the suggestion worked) you can accept it by clicking the tick symbol right under the points indicator, so that the question does not remain open.